# Okta factor activation using Go SDK

Tags: go, okta

The [documentation](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-golang#activate-a-factor) specifies this code to activate a factor:

```
...
ctx, client, err := okta.NewClient(context, okta.WithOrgUrl("https://{yourOktaDomain}"), okta.WithToken("{apiToken}"))

factor, resp, err := client.Factor.ActivateFactor(user.Id, factor.Id, nil)
...
```

But in practice I needed some changes:

```
...
ctx, client, err := okta.NewClient(context, okta.WithOrgUrl("https://{yourOktaDomain}"), okta.WithToken("{apiToken}"))


activationRequest := *okta.NewActivateFactorRequest()

//What information should the activationRequest be completed with? 
//Is it completely necessary?

factor, resp, err := client.UserFactor.ActivateFactor(ctx, userID, factorID, activationRequest, nil)
...
```

The type of `activationRequest` is:

```
type ActivateFactorRequest struct {
    Attestation      string `json:"attestation,omitempty"`
    ClientData       string `json:"clientData,omitempty"`
    PassCode         string `json:"passCode,omitempty"`
    RegistrationData string `json:"registrationData,omitempty"`
    StateToken       string `json:"stateToken,omitempty"`
}
```

The main question here is: **What information should the activation request activationRequest be completed with?**

Since the documentation for the Okta SDK for Go seems to be not entirely complete, I don't know where to find more references on the process to activate the factor.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. In this part

```
...
ctx, client, err := okta.NewClient(context, okta.WithOrgUrl("https://{yourOktaDomain}"), okta.WithToken("{apiToken}"))


activationRequest := *okta.NewActivateFactorRequest()
activationRequest.PassCode = passCode // The access code sent to your email

factor, resp, err := client.UserFactor.ActivateFactor(ctx, userID, factorID, activationRequest, nil)
...
```

No more information is needed in the activationRequest to activate the email factor